# When writing webpack configuration in TypeScript, what typings to use when module.exports is a function?

Tags: typescript, webpack, typescript-generics

I have this in my `webpack.config.ts`:

```js
import * as webpack from 'webpack'

module.exports = (env, argv): webpack.Configuration => {
  return {};
}
```

But it’s unclear to me what types I should use for `env` and `argv`.

I couldn’t find the answer in Webpack documentation, anywhere on the web or in my code editor suggestion, and I couldn’t make sense of the webpack typing files. The closer I have is the description in [the Configuration Types of the webpack documentation](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/configuration-types/#exporting-a-function), but it’s unclear what the exact type is.

Answer (score 1):

From the [webpack bug tracker](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/11630#issuecomment-946688782), I learned that there are no dedicated types defined (at least right now). Instead, one of the correct options is to use these types:

```js
module.exports = (
  env: Record<string, any>,
  argv: Record<string, any>,
): webpack.Configuration => {
  return {};
}
```